# OpenCV get topdown view of planar pattern by using intrinsic and extrinsic from cameraCalibrate

Tags: computer-vision, cameras, calibration, opencv

Originally I have a image with a perfect circle grid, denoted as ***A***
[image]
I add some lens distortion and perspective transformation to it, and it becomes  ***B***
[image]
In camera calibration, ***A*** would be my destination image, and ***B*** would be my source image.
Let's say I have all the circle center coordinates in both images, stored in *stdPts* and *disPts*.

```
//25 center pts in A
vector<Point2f> stdPts;
for (int i = 0; i <= 4; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= 4; ++j) {
        stdPts[i * 5 + j].x = 250 + i * 500;
        stdPts[i * 5 + j].y = 200 + j * 400;
    }
}
//25 center pts in B
vector<Point2f> disPts = FindCircleCenter();
```

I want to generate an image ***C*** that is as close as ***A***, from input: ***B***, *stdPts* and *disPts*.
I tried to use the intrinsic and extrinsic generated by cv::calibrateCamera. Here is my code:

```
//prepare object_points and image_points
vector<vector<Point3f>> object_points;
vector<vector<Point2f>> image_points;
object_points.push_back(stdPts);
image_points.push_back(disPts);


//prepare distCoeffs rvecs tvecs
Mat distCoeffs = Mat::zeros(5, 1, CV_64F);
vector<Mat> rvecs;
vector<Mat> tvecs;


//prepare camera matrix
Mat intrinsic = Mat::eye(3, 3, CV_64F);

//solve calibration
calibrateCamera(object_points, image_points, Size(2500,2000), intrinsic, distCoeffs, rvecs, tvecs);


//apply undistortion
string inputName = "../B.jpg";
Mat imgB = imread(imgName);
cvtColor(imgB, imgB, CV_BGR2GRAY)
Mat tempImgC;
undistort(imgB, tempImgC, intrinsic, distCoeffs);


//apply perspective transform
double transData[] = { 0, 0, tvecs[0].at<double>(0), 0, 0,,tvecs[0].at<double>(1), 0, 0,  tvecs[0].at<double>(2) };
Mat translate3x3(3, 3, CV_64F, transData);
Mat rotation3x3;
Rodrigues(rvecs[0], rotation3x3);

Mat transRot3x3(3, 3, CV_64F);
rotation3x3.col(0).copyTo(transRot3x3.col(0));
rotation3x3.col(1).copyTo(transRot3x3.col(1));
translate3x3.col(2).copyTo(transRot3x3.col(2));

Mat imgC;
Mat matPerspective = intrinsic*transRot3x3;
warpPerspective(tempImgC, imgC, matPerspective, Size(2500, 2000));

//write
string outputName = "../C.jpg";
imwrite(outputName, imgC); // A JPG FILE IS BEING SAVED
```

And here is the result image ***C***, which doesn't deal with the perspective transformation at all.
[image]

So could someone teach me how to recover ***A***? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Added**

OK, guys, simple mistake. I previously used *warpPerspective* to warp images instead of restoring. Since it works that way, I didn't read [the doc](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#void%20warpPerspective(InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20InputArray%20M,%20Size%20dsize,%20int%20flags,%20int%20borderMode,%20const%20Scalar&%20borderValue)) thoroughly. It turns out that if it is for restoring, the flag *WARP_INVERSE_MAP* should be set. Change the function call to this, and that's it.

```
warpPerspective(tempImgC, imgC, matPerspective, Size(2500, 2000), WARP_INVERSE_MAP);
```

Here is the **new result image** ***C***:
[image]

The only thing concerns me now is the intermediary *tempImgC*, which is the image after *undistort* and before *warpPerspective*. In some tests with different artificial ***B*** s, This image could turn out to be a scaled-up version of ***B*** with distortion removed. That means a lot of information is lost in the outter area. And there is not much to use for *warpPerspective*. I'm thinking maybe to scale down the image in *undistort* and to scale it up in *warpPerspective*. But I'm not sure yet how to calculate the correct scale to preserve all the information in ***B***.

**Added 2**

The last piece of the puzzle is in place. Call *getOptimalNewCameraMatrix* before *undistort* to generate the new camera matrix that preserves all the info in *B*. And pass this new camera matrix to *undistort* and *warpPerspective.*

```
Mat newIntrinsic=getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(intrinsic, distCoeffs, Size(2500, 2000), 1);
undistort(imgB, tempImgC, intrinsic, distCoeffs, newIntrinsic);
Mat matPerspective = newIntrinsic*transRot3x3;
warpPerspective(tempImgC, imgC, matPerspective, Size(2500, 2000), WARP_INVERSE_MAP);
```

The result image ***C*** is the same in this case. But there is a big difference for other cases. For example, with another distorted image ***B1***.
[image]
The result image ***C1*** without new camera matrix looks like this.
[image]
And the result image ***C1*** with new camera matrix maintains the information in ***B1***
[image]

**Added 3**

I realized that as each frame captured by camera needs processing and efficiency is important, I can't afford to use `undistort` and `warpPerspective` for each frame. It's only reasonable to have one map and use `remap` for each frame.

Actually, there is a straight forward way to that, which is `projectPoints`. Since it generates the map from destination image to source image directly, **no intermediary image is needed** and thus loss of information is avoided.

```
// ....
//solve calibration

//generate a 3-channel mat with each entry containing it's own coordinates
Mat xyz(2000, 2500, CV_32FC3);
float *pxyz = (float*)xyz.data;
for (int y = 0; y < 2000; y++)
    for (int x = 0; x < 2500; x++)
    {
        *pxyz++ = x;
        *pxyz++ = y;
        *pxyz++ = 0;
    }

// project coordinates of destination image,
// which generates the map from destination image to source image directly
xyz=xyz.reshape(0, 5000000);
Mat mapToSrc(5000000, 1, CV_32FC2);
projectPoints(xyz, rvecs[0], tvecs[0], intrinsic, distCoeffs, mapToSrc);
Mat maps[2];
mapToSrc = mapToSrc.reshape(0, 2000);
split(mapToSrc, maps);

//apply map
remap(imgB, imgC, maps[0], maps[1], INTER_LINEAR);
```

Comment: This is a great answer, and super-useful. But I was wondering if it was possible for you to post your final code, rather than the subsequent snippets? I'm confused about whether or not you still needed to call PerpectiveTransform, since it seems to have disappeared in your last code snippet.